# Duplicate an array dimension

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array, indexing

I have a numpy Array with many dimensions and I want to duplicate one of the dimensions to a new dimension. For example, if I have

```
A = np.eye(2)
>>> np.eye(2)
array([[ 1.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  1.]])
```

I want to create an array B with an added dimesnion that is a duplicate of dimension 1, in the following sense. I want that for each coordinate a in dimension 0, and b

```
B[a,b,:] = B[a,:,b]
```

I tried np.tile and np.repeat, but those methods give me an array where

```
B[a,b,:] = array([A[a,b], A[a,b], ...])
```

For the identity example above, I would want the following array

```
array([[ 1.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  1.]],

       [[ 0.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  0.]])
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: It's not at all clear what you're trying to achieve. Your two descriptions contradict each other.

Comment: Sorry, got confused while writing the question. I hope it's clear now.

Comment: Suppose `A = np.arange(4).reshape([2, 2])`. What should `B` look like? It seems like what you're describing may not actually be possible.

Comment: I am sure it's possible. Essentially I want to mirror an axis, so that for any coordinate in the array moving one step in direction 1 or 2 is the same.

Comment: But then if you move all the way to the end of the array in direction 1, what value do you get when you move in direction 2? You're out of elements from the original array.

Comment: Your last example shows a mirrored 2D array, like your comment (but note that it's not anything valid. Looks like there's a missing set of brackets?). But the line `B[a,b,:] = B[a,:,b]` indicates things are not mirrored, but the second and third axis (1-based) are identical. Which one do you want?

Comment: Simplest way with your example: `np.dstack([a, a])`.

Comment: Have you looked at `repeat` and/or `tile`?

Answer (score 2):

I am not entirely sure what you are asking. However, using `numpy.flipr(X)` where `X` is a `numpy.array()` might be what you're looking for. It flips the array in the left/right direction. See code below.

```
import numpy as np
X1 = np.array([[1,0], [0,1]])
X2 = np.fliplr(X1)
X = np.array([X1, X2])
print X
```

Returns:

```
[[[1 0]
  [0 1]]

 [[0 1]
  [1 0]]]
```

Comment: equivalently, `np.array((A, A[::-1,:]))`